# Assigning redis values/redis hash entries to Type T returns null value

Tags: c#, json, redis

I am getting NULL properties on the below code, while returning the hashed value in cacheData

Line where I get Null values for all properties:
**var val = RedisUtils.ToHashEntries(db.HashGet(hashkey + ":" + clsobjname, id));**

**cacheData = RedisUtils.ConvertFromRedis(e);**
[image]

Please help me to assign the hashedValues(HashGet/HashGetAll values) to type T CacheData

**Code:**

public class class1
{

public class SampleModel

```
    {
        public SampleModel()
        {
            EmployeeDetails = new List<employees>();
            CountryDetails = new List<country>();
            StateDetails = new List<State>();
        }

        public List<employees> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
        public List<country> CountryDetails { get; set; }
        public List<State> StateDetails { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class employees
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
    [Serializable]
    public class country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string countryName { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

    } 
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
    private readonly IConfiguration _Configuration;
    private int cacheTypeAll;
    private int cacheTypeMaster;

    public class1(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
        _Configuration = configuration;
        cacheTypeAll = _Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<int>("CacheInstance");
        cacheTypeMaster = _Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<int>("CacheInstanceMaster");
    }
    public async Task<T> GetRedisHash<T>(string hashkey, string id, SampleModel obj) where T : class
    {
        var db = _connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase(cacheTypeAll);
        T cacheData = null;
        foreach (var a in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var clsobjname = a.Name;
            var HashGetAll = db.HashGetAll(hashkey + ":" + clsobjname);
            var hashget = db.HashGet(hashkey + ":" + clsobjname, id);
            if (HashGetAll.ToHashSet().Count > 0)
            {
                if (clsobjname != null)
                {
                    if (id != "")
                    {
                        var e = RedisUtils.ToHashEntries(db.HashGet(hashkey + ":" + clsobjname, id));
                        cacheData = RedisUtils.ConvertFromRedis<T>(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var d = RedisUtils.ToHashEntries(db.HashGetAll(hashkey + ":" + clsobjname));
                        cacheData = RedisUtils.ConvertFromRedis<T>(d);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //cacheData = await computeData();
               // string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cacheData);
                string serializedData = "{'EmployeeDetails':[{'Id':1,'FirstName':'Anderson','LastName':'Felipe'},{'Id':2,'FirstName':'Anita','LastName':'Kay'},{'Id':3,'FirstName':'Karte','LastName':'Hare'}],'CountryDetails':[{'Id':1,'Name':'UK'}],'StateDetails':[{'Id':1,'Name':'UK'}]}";//I have set it static
                dynamic parseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedData);
                foreach (var h in parseJson)
                {
                    var c = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)h)).Value;
                    var objname = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)h).Name;
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (var b in c)
                    {
                        var Id = c[i]["Id"];
                        db.HashSet(hashkey + ":" + objname, new HashEntry[] {
                            new HashEntry(Id.ToString(),JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c[i]))});
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            clsobjname = "";
        }
        return cacheData;
    }
}
public static class RedisUtils
{
   // Serialize in Redis format:
    public static HashEntry[] ToHashEntries(this object obj)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        return properties.Select(property => new HashEntry(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj).ToString())).ToArray();
    }
   
    //Deserialize from Redis format
    public static T ConvertFromRedis<T>(this HashEntry[] hashEntries)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            HashEntry entry = hashEntries.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name.ToString().Equals(property.Name));
            if (entry.Equals(new HashEntry())) continue;
            property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(entry.Value.ToString(), property.PropertyType));
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi All, Any suggestion on this.... where its going wrong?